# Can a US non-resident alien do tax-loss harvesting on capital gains and income? (183-day rule)

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, non-resident, capital-loss

Context: I am a non-resident alien in the USA as a J1 scholar. After being present for 183 days in the USA, I must pay capital gains tax in the USA. My questions:

- i) can I reduce my ordinary USA taxable income with capital-losses (up to $3000/year), just like an American?
- ii) if my realized capital gains are less than my losses, then am I effectively absolved from taxation on the gains (regardless of the amount)?

The distinction with the second question is the amount: as in whether there is any relevancy to the $3000 limit when one's gains are dwarfed by losses, of any amount.